# pythonにてcv2エラーが発生します。

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, コマンドプロンプト

解決できないエラーが発生したので知恵をお借りしたいです。

エラー箇所

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exer1.py", line 20, in <module>
    img = np.float64( cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) )
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.2.0) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'
```

以下エラー部分のコードです。

```
import numpy as np
import sys
import cv2

#load image
fname_in  = sys.argv[1]
fname_out = sys.argv[2]
img = cv2.imread(fname_in)

#輝度画像へ変換（平均値がオーバーフローしないようfloat64にキャスト）
img = np.float64( cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY) )

#---------------------------

mean_value = 0
H = img.shape[0]
W = img.shape[1]
for y in range(H):
    for x in range(W):  
        mean_value += img[y,x]

mean_value = mean_value / (H*W)

#---------------------------

#値をファイルに入れて出力
f = open(fname_out, "w")
f.write( str(mean_value) )
f.close()
```

コマンドプロンプトでは以下のように実行しました。
python exer1.py img1.png fname_out.txt

Comment: 実行時に引数で画像ファイルを指定するようにプログラムしているようなので、コマンドプロンプトで入力したコマンドも質問に含めたほうがよいかもしれません。 / 合わせて、指定した画像ファイルが存在するのかもまず確認してみてください。

Comment: こちらの記事が版数は違いますが同様のケースでしょう。[OpenCV !_src.empty() in function 'cvtColor' error](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52676020/9014308)

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございました。無事解決いたしました。